# Can I implement payment gateway in fire tv app for buy subscription?

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-fire-tv

Please explain how to implement payment gateway in fire tv app for buy subscription.

Please explain how to implement payment gateway in fire tv app for buy subscription.

Comment: You should ask clearly.

Answer (score 0):

To implement the Subscriptions in your app for Fire TV you can follow the guide here

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-overview.html